# Full-width tab bar that has equal left/right padding between text and tab edges

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, padding

I have a tab bar that needs to expand 100% of the page layout. Instead of having an equal width for each tab, I need them to have an equal amount of left/right padding between the left/right sides of the text to the edge of the tab. (note how there's a lot of space in all the tabs except for Product Details)

Can this be accomplished using pure CSS? If not, how could it be done using jQuery?

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="product-details.html">Products Detail</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
}

nav {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

nav ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #616161;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

ul {
  display: table-row;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}

.x {
  display: none;
}

.p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.d {
  color: #ccc;
}

@media (max-width: 430px) {

  nav {
    font-size: .8em;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  }

}
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thebluehorse/g4w9nbky/).

Comment: I dont know what you want. Can you explain it again plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the closest you'll get using pure css is changing table-layout to auto:

```
nav {
  display: table;
  table-layout: auto;
}
```

Comment: You could get even closer by adding left/right padding to the links `padding:10px;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox:

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/2eqk1kcs/

However you should look at the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox).